# Ignore Lightning Application with .forceignore

Tags: salesforcedx, .forceignore

Using SalesforceDX, I am currently having trouble finding a way to ignore a lightning application created in my scratch org; the force:source:status always seem to include it.

The name of the Aura bundle is "preview" and the current .forceignore file read this :

```
package.xml
preview\preview.app
preview
**preview
```

The file is placed at the root of the project and works fine when I try to ignore other files such as a given object or profile. But when it comes to AuraDefinitionBundle, I am having trouble finding out the right exclusion syntax. As seen above, I tried to exclude the app file which is the name that the force:source:status command return me for the application, the folder name or any folder with that name.

Nothing seems to work and I figured it might be rather simple but I am missing it and the documentation on this seems limited on salesforce side. I tried a bunch of other things from related .gitignore doc but without success.

Comment: You normally need to use / instead of \. I think it should look something like `**/aura/preview/*`

Comment: DX is supposed to use the [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) format. Does this help?

Comment: @sfdcfox I tried replacing the slashes and toyed with the suggestion, nothing worked for that. Also I looked into the gitignore and tried a couple of stuff but I am not quite the advanced user of git.

I feel like in git it would work given the folder structure it comes out as when I pull aura bundles from an org, but I just have no success currently with it and I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I've had great trouble getting my head round the various forceignore syntaxes.
As of now (my version is sfdx-cli/7.48.0-a71f8c6899) the following is what I've found for Aura Definition Bundle entries (note I'm unsure why the OP's `preview` entry did not work);

- You don't need to supply an extension (unlike the other meta)
- Be careful that the entries have implicit wild carding.

An example;
If my `sfdx force:source:status` return this;

```
STATE       FULL NAME              TYPE                  PROJECT PATH
──────────  ─────────────────────  ────────────────────  ────────────
Remote Add  setExpId/setExpId.evt  AuraDefinitionBundle
```

Then I can ignore that `setExpId` bundle with this entry in the .forceignore;

```
setExpId
```